Where should I put my pages in order for Next.js Link component to find them?
I am making a website with Next.js and Tailwind CSS, and I am trying to navigate from the landing page to the about page.
The code below is my Link tag inside of the header component:
<Link href="/AboutUs" >
     <p className={`pb-5 pl-5 cursor-pointer text-darksand opacity-50`}>About</p>
</Link>

My pages AboutUs.jsx and Landing.jsx are in a folder app/pages/*jsx and Header.jsx is in app/components/Header.jsx. I am using the Header.jsx file in the landing page as following:
app
|   favicon.ico
│   globals.css
│   layout.js
│   page.js
│
├───components
│       footer.jsx
│       Header.jsx
├───pages
│       AboutUs.jsx
│       Landing.jsx

The Link component works fine for the same page (i.e., scrolling to an anchor using <Link href="/#name">), but whenever I try to navigate to a different page, it gives me a 404 response. All of the resources I have found online say to put my pages inside of a "pages" folder inside the app directory and then use ../page-name, but that hasn't worked.
How do I access the other pages in my pages folder using the Link tag?

I think you have it the other way around; the page name should be the folder, and the page itself will always be called page.jsx inside that subdirectory.
app
|   favicon.ico
│   globals.css
│   layout.js
│   page.js
│
├───components
│       footer.jsx
│       Header.jsx
│
├───AboutUs
│       page.jsx
│
├───Landing
│       page.jsx


Here, you are using App router. So for that any folder creation in app , it will be consider as a new route . Make sure to create a file with the name page.tsx in that folder.
app
|   favicon.ico
│   globals.css
│   layout.js
│   page.js
│
├───components
│       footer.jsx
│       Header.jsx
│
├───about-us
│       page.jsx
│
├───terms-and-conditions
│       page.jsx

Please check for APP router details
Also refer this for naming convention of routes
